# SVN Export while retaining permissions

Tags: svn, svn-export

I have some files in my SVN repository that I would like to have execute permissions.  When I check them into the repository with 755 permissions and run an svn export, the resulting files have 644 permissions.

There doesn't appear to be an option in "svn export" to retain the permissions. Am I missing something?

Thanks-

Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that subversion only supports svn:executable.

777 is a pretty wide open selection.  This suggests that you are trying to have a writable file.

You may want to put that in a separate directory outside the svn export directory.

Comment: I want my exported files to have 755 permissions.  I've edited the initial question accordingly.

Thnks-
Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option is to use svn:executable

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.executable